# Windows Cluster - High Availability for a software

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

How can I ensure that a software installed on a cluster is always available.
I understand that I can install the software in a shared drive and if one node goes down, the other node will take care.
But what about the windows system dependencies like the registries, windows dir, 
services etc?
Will these things as well get shared across the node?

Basically if I have a software written in C++/C# which has lots of windows O/S resource dependencies(registry, service etc), how can I ensure that it is highly available through a cluster? Is it possible?

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, let's assume:

1. There are two servers in the cluster. ServerA and ServerB.
2. Each server has their own local drive. (C:)
3. Each server has access to a shared/common drive called F:\ (probably on an external SAN)

When installing or updating your application on the Failover Cluster, first ensure ServerA is the cluster owner/active node. Install your application as usual, insuring the install path is a folder on the shared drive F:.

Once the install is complete to ServerA, go into Failover Cluster manager and make ServerB the cluster owner/active node. Repeat the install on ServerB, using the same folder on F:\ for the installation path.

If your application is a Windows service (or set of services), make sure after the application installation that you configure the service as a *Generic Service Resource* in the Failover Cluster. Then, always stop/start the service via Failover Cluster Manager